# Label encoding across multiple columns with same attributes in sckit-learn

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

If I have two columns as below:

```
Origin  Destination  
China   USA  
China   Turkey  
USA     China  
USA     Turkey  
USA     Russia  
Russia  China
```

How would I perform label encoding while ensuring the label for the Origin column matches the one in the destination column i.e

```
Origin  Destination  
0   1  
0   3  
1   0  
1   0  
1   0  
2   1
```

If I do the encoding for each column separately then the algorithm will see the China in column1 as different from column2 which is not the case

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**`pandas` Method**

You could create a dictionary of `{country: value}` pairs and map the dataframe to that:

```
country_map = {country:i for i, country in enumerate(df.stack().unique())}

df['Origin'] = df['Origin'].map(country_map)    
df['Destination'] = df['Destination'].map(country_map)

>>> df
   Origin  Destination
0       0            1
1       0            2
2       1            0
3       1            2
4       1            3
5       3            0
```

**`sklearn` method**

Since you tagged `sklearn`, you could use [`LabelEncoder()`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html):

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
le= LabelEncoder()
le.fit(df.stack().unique())

df['Origin'] = le.transform(df['Origin'])
df['Destination'] = le.transform(df['Destination'])

>>> df
   Origin  Destination
0       0            3
1       0            2
2       3            0
3       3            2
4       3            1
5       1            0
```

To get the original labels back:

```
>>> le.inverse_transform(df['Origin'])
# array(['China', 'China', 'USA', 'USA', 'USA', 'Russia'], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 8):

### `stack`

```
df.stack().pipe(lambda s: pd.Series(pd.factorize(s.values)[0], s.index)).unstack()

   Origin  Destination
0       0            1
1       0            2
2       1            0
3       1            2
4       1            3
5       3            0
```

---

### `factorize` with `reshape`

```
pd.DataFrame(
    pd.factorize(df.values.ravel())[0].reshape(df.shape),
    df.index, df.columns
)

   Origin  Destination
0       0            1
1       0            2
2       1            0
3       1            2
4       1            3
5       3            0
```

---

### `np.unique` and `reshape`

```
pd.DataFrame(
    np.unique(df.values.ravel(), return_inverse=True)[1].reshape(df.shape),
    df.index, df.columns
)

   Origin  Destination
0       0            3
1       0            2
2       3            0
3       3            2
4       3            1
5       1            0
```

---

### Disgusting Option

I couldn't stop trying stuff... sorry!

```
df.applymap(
    lambda x, y={}, c=itertools.count():
        y.get(x) if x in y else y.setdefault(x, next(c))
)

   Origin  Destination
0       0            1
1       0            3
2       1            0
3       1            3
4       1            2
5       2            0
```

---

As pointed out by [cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4909087/c%e1%b4%8f%ca%9f%e1%b4%85s%e1%b4%98%e1%b4%87%e1%b4%87%e1%b4%85)

You can shorten this by assigning back to dataframe

```
df[:] = pd.factorize(df.values.ravel())[0].reshape(df.shape)
```

Comment: You can shorten `factorize`: `df[:] = pd.factorize(df.values.ravel())[0].reshape(df.shape)`

Comment: Very true!  But that goes against my general tendency to avoid overwriting the dataframe (-:

Answer (score 5):

You can using `replace`

```
df.replace(dict(zip(np.unique(df.values),list(range(len(np.unique(df.values)))))))
   Origin  Destination
0       0            3
1       0            2
2       3            0
3       3            2
4       3            1
5       1            0
```

Succinct and nice answer from Pir

```
df.replace((lambda u: dict(zip(u, range(u.size))))(np.unique(df)))
```

And

```
df.replace(dict(zip(np.unique(df), itertools.count())))
```

Comment: `df.replace((lambda u: dict(zip(u, range(u.size))))(np.unique(df)))`

Comment: Even better `df.replace(dict(zip(np.unique(df), itertools.count())))`

Answer (score 3):

Edit: just found out about `return_inverse` option to `np.unique`. No need to search and substitute!

```
df.values[:] = np.unique(df, return_inverse=True)[1].reshape(-1,2)
```

You could leverage the vectorized version of `np.searchsorted` with

```
df.values[:] = np.searchsorted(np.sort(np.unique(df)), df)
```

Or you could create an array of one-hot encodings and recover indices with argmax. Probably not a great idea if there are many countries.

```
df.values[:] = (df.values[...,None] == np.unique(df)).argmax(-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `LabelEncoder` from `sklearn`, you can also try:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing

le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le.fit(df.values.flatten())

df = df.apply(le.fit_transform)
print(df)
```

Result:

```
   Origin  Destination
0       0            3
1       0            2
2       2            0
3       2            2
4       2            1
5       1            0
```

If you have more columns and only want to apply to selected columns of dataframe then, you can try:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()

# columns to select for encoding
selected_col = ['Origin','Destination']
le.fit(df[selected_col].values.flatten())

df[selected_col] = df[selected_col].apply(le.fit_transform)
print(df)
```